# Given a data matrix, calculate html rowspan and colspan

Tags: javascript

I have a sparse matrix like below consisting of data cells (1..9) and empty cells (=zero):

```
[
    [ 1, 2, 0, 3 ],
    [ 0, 4, 0, 0 ],
    [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ],
]
```

I'd like to display this as an html table, but there should be no empty cells - they should be "covered" by their neighbouring data cells' row- and colspans:

```
<table border=1 cellpadding=10>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>1</td>
        <td colspan=2>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

(this is one possible implementation, we could also use `colspan=4` on the second row and no rowspan).

Generating actual html is not a problem, but I have trouble writing an algorithm to calculate row and column spans for data cells.

**EDIT**: still looking for an answer for this. It seems to be trivial to work with colspans only and concatenate each data cell with empty cells on its left/right. However, I'd like cells to be as square shaped as possible, so the answer should include rowspan logic as well. Thanks!

**EDIT2**: all answers so far summarized here: http://jsfiddle.net/ThQt4/

Comment: Should a cell be allowed a colspan and a rowspan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things to consider in what you want.

If you always prefer squares over the biggest shape, you could end up with a lot of single rows an colums, because a rectangle **always** starts with a square. And a square or rectangle can only start if the top-left part has a value.

Consider this array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 2, 0, 0, 5]
```

If you choose squares over the biggest shape you'll end up with a square and three columns

```
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] instead of [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
[  7  ] [ ] [ ] [ ]            [        7        ]
[     ] [ ] [ ] [ ]            [                 ]
```

Furthermore, you could end up with empty single cells:

```
[1, 1, 2, 0],   gives   [1] [1] [  2  ]
[3, 0, 0, 0],           [         ] [?] <---
[0, 0, 0, 5],           [    3    ] [5]
[0, 0, 0, 1]            [         ] [1]
```

The largest square here is size 3x3 starting with 3. If you first claim the 3x3 and then the row starting with 2, you'll end up with an empty cell `[?]` above 5.

One last thing, if you have zeros in the top row or left column, you could also end up in trouble:

```
                                             V
[1, 0, 0, 2],  will leave you with  [  1  ] [?] [2]
[0, 0, 3, 4],                       [     ] [3] [4]
[0, 5, 6, 7]                    --->[?] [5] [6] [7]
```

That said, maybe your array isn't that complicated and maybe you don't mind the empty cells. In either way, it was fun solving this puzzle with your specs. My solution obeys the following rules:

1) squares go first.

2) Size matters. The bigger, the better

3) Rows and colums: Size matters. The biggest go first.

4) Colspan goes over rowspan

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S64ra/5/)

```
var maxv = arr.length;
var maxh = arr[0].length;
var rsv = [];
var rsh = [];
pop_arr();
var shape;
try_sq();
try_rect();
try_loose();


//TRY SQUARES FIRST
function try_sq() {
    var sv, sh;
    shape = [];
    for (sv = 0; sv < maxv - 1; sv++) {
        for (sh = 0; sh < maxh - 1; sh++) {
            if (arr[sv][sh] === 0 || rsv[sv][sh] > -1 || rsh[sv][sh] > -1) {
                continue;
            }
            check_sq(sv, sh);
        }
    }
    if (shape.length > 0) {
        occu();
    }
}


//TRY RECTANGLES
function try_rect() {
    var sv, sh;
    var rect = false;
    do {
        shape = [];
        for (sv = 0; sv < maxv; sv++) {
            for (sh = 0; sh < maxh; sh++) {
                if (arr[sv][sh] === 0 || rsv[sv][sh] > -1 || rsh[sv][sh] > -1) continue;
                check_rec(sv, sh);
            }
        }
        if (shape.length > 0) {
            occu();
        } else {
            rect = false;
        }
    } while (rect === true);
}

//TRY LOOSE
function try_loose() {
    var sv, sh;
    //SET THE 1x1 with value
    for (sv = 0; sv < maxv; sv++) {
        for (sh = 0; sh < maxh; sh++) {
            if (arr[sv][sh] !== 0 && (rsv[sv][sh] == -1 || rsh[sv][sh] == -1)) {
                rsv[sv][sh] = 1;
                rsh[sv][sh] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    //SEARCH FOR rectangles wit no value
    var rect = true;
    do {
        shape = [];
        for (sv = 0; sv < maxv; sv++) {
            for (sh = 0; sh < maxh; sh++) {
                if (arr[sv][sh] !== 0 || (rsv[sv][sh] > -1 || rsh[sv][sh] > -1)) {
                    continue;
                }
                rect = check_loose(sv, sh);
            }
        }
        if (shape.length > 0) occu();
        else {
            rect = false;
        }
    } while (rect === true);
}


//check SINGLES 
function check_loose(start_v, start_h) {
    var vd, hd, iv, ih, rect;
    var hor = ver = 1;
    var horb = 0;
    var mxv = maxv - 1;
    var mxh = maxh - 1;
    rect = true;
    vd = start_v + ver;
    hd = start_h + hor;

    //check horizontal
    for (sh = start_h + 1; sh <= mxh; sh++) {
        if (arr[start_v][sh] !== 0 || rsh[start_v][sh] > -1) {
            break;
        }
        hor++;
    }
    //check vertical
    for (iv = start_v + 1; iv <= mxv; iv++) {
        if (arr[iv][start_h] !== 0 || rsh[iv][start_h] > -1) {
            break;
        }
        ver++;
    }
    if (hor > ver || hor == ver) {
        shape.unshift({
            0: (hor),
            1: [start_v, start_h, 1, hor]
        });
        return true;
    } else if (ver > hor) {
        shape.push({
            0: (ver),
            1: [start_v, start_h, ver, 1]
        });
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}




//check SQUARE        
function check_sq(start_v, start_h) {
    if (arr[start_v + 1][start_h] !== 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (arr[start_v][start_h + 1] !== 0) {
        return false;
    }
    var vd, hd, sv, sh, square;
    var hor = ver = 1;
    var mxv = maxv - 1;
    var mxh = maxh - 1;
    //CHECK DIAGONAL
    do {
        square = true;
        vd = start_v + ver;
        hd = start_h + hor;
        //diagonal OK
        if (arr[vd][hd] !== 0) {
            if (hor == 1) {
                if (ver == 1) {
                    return false;
                }
                square = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        //check horizontal
        for (sh = start_h; sh <= hd; sh++) {
            if (arr[vd][sh] !== 0) {
                square = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (square === false) break;
        //check vertical
        for (sv = start_v; sv <= vd; sv++) {
            if (arr[sv][hd] !== 0) {
                square = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (square === false) break;
        hor++;
        ver++;
    } while (square === true && vd < mxv && hd < mxh);
    //SQUARE OK
    if (hor > 1 && ver > 1 && hor == ver) {
        shape.push({
            0: (hor * ver),
            1: [start_v, start_h, ver, hor]
        });
    }
}


//check RECTANGLE
function check_rec(start_v, start_h) {
    var vd, hd, iv, ih, rect;
    var hor = ver = 1;
    var horb = 0;
    var mxv = maxv - 1;
    var mxh = maxh - 1;
    rect = true;
    vd = start_v + ver;
    hd = start_h + hor;

    //check horizontal
    if (start_h < maxh) {
        for (sh = start_h + 1; sh <= mxh; sh++) {
            if (arr[start_v][sh] !== 0 || rsh[start_v][sh] > -1) break;
            hor++;
        }
    }
    //check vertical
    if (start_v < maxv) {
        for (iv = start_v + 1; iv <= mxv; iv++) {
            if (arr[iv][start_h] !== 0 || rsh[iv][start_h] > -1) break;
            ver++;
        }
    }
    if (hor == 1 && ver == 1) return false;
    if (hor > ver || hor == ver) {
        shape.unshift({
            0: (hor),
            1: [start_v, start_h, 1, hor]
        });
        return true;
    } else {
        shape.push({
            0: (ver),
            1: [start_v, start_h, ver, 1]
        });
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


//FIND LARGEST SHAPE
function occu() {
    var le = shape.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < le; i++) {
        var b = Math.max.apply(Math, shape.map(function (v) {
            return v[0];
        }));
        for (var j = 0; j < shape.length; j++) {
            if (shape[j][0] == b) break;
        }
        var c = shape.splice(j, 1);
        claim(c[0][1]);
    }
}


//CLAIM SHAPE
function claim(sh) {
    var iv, ih;
    for (iv = sh[0]; iv < sh[0] + sh[2]; iv++) {
        for (ih = sh[1]; ih < sh[1] + sh[3]; ih++) {
            if (rsv[iv][ih] > -1 || rsh[iv][ih] > -1) return false;
        }
    }
    for (iv = sh[0]; iv < sh[0] + sh[2]; iv++) {
        for (ih = sh[1]; ih < sh[1] + sh[3]; ih++) {
            rsv[iv][ih] = 0;
            rsh[iv][ih] = 0;
        }
    }
    rsv[sh[0]][sh[1]] = sh[2];
    rsh[sh[0]][sh[1]] = sh[3];
}

function pop_arr() {
    var em = [];
    em[0] = arr[0].concat();
    for (var i = 0; i < maxh; i++) {
        em[0][i] = -1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < maxv; i++) {
        rsv[i] = em[0].concat();
        rsh[i] = em[0].concat();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You want it as square-shaped as possible? I'd say, you want to prioritize the biggest area. 
Now to the algoritm. First, let's make the matrix a little bit bigger:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XiozZe/pkBxE/)

And this is where I came up with:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XiozZe/pkBxE/6/)

It's using these simple steps:

1. It calculates all possible widths and heights a rectangle has to have if it wants to find in the matrix.
2. It sorts these values first on if their square or not, prioritizing squares, then on area: from a big area to a small one.
3. Then it tries to fit in each rectangle, from big to small.
4. A rectangle "fits" if there is 1 number in the rectangle, and at least 1 zero.
5. If it fits, he leaves a mark there, so all rectangle after this one can't use those cells.
6. It ends when there are no zero's left.

Done.

```
var Omatrix = [   //Original matrix
    [ 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 2 ],
    [ 0, 4, 0, 0, 7, 0, 4 ],
    [ 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 0 ],
    [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 4, 0, 0, 7, 2, 4 ],
    [ 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 9, 3 ],
];

var matrix = []
for (var i = 0; i < Omatrix.length; i++){
    matrix[i] = Omatrix[i].slice(0);
}

//calculating all possible lengths
var a = matrix[0].length;
//maximum rectangle width
var b = matrix.length;
//maximum rectangle height

//calculate the area of each rectangle and save it using an array
var array = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= b; j++) {
        array.push({"width":i, "height":j, "area":i*j, "square":i===j});
    }
}

//sort first on square, then on area: biggest first
array.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.square === b.square){
        x = b.area;
        y = a.area;
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    }
    else{
        return a.square? -1:1;
    }
});    

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    //working from biggest area to smallest
    for(var j = 0; j < matrix.length-array[i].width+1; j++){
        //working from left to right
        notfound:
        for(var k = 0; k < matrix[0].length-array[i].height+1; k++){
            //working from top to bottom
            var nonzero = false;
            var zero = false
            //checking if there is exactly one number and atleast one zero
            for(var l = 0; l < array[i].width; l++){
                //working from left to right
                for(var m = 0; m < array[i].height; m++){
                    //working from top to bottom
                    if(matrix[j+l][k+m] > 0){
                        if(!nonzero){
                            //we have found the first number 
                            //and saved that number for later use
                            nonzero = matrix[j+l][k+m];
                        }
                        else{
                            //we have found a second number:
                            //break and go to the next square
                            continue notfound;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(matrix[j+l][k+m] === 0){
                        //this is a zero
                        zero = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        //there is already a square build from this block
                        continue notfound;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!nonzero || !zero){
                //there isn't a number here
                //or there isn't a zero here
                continue notfound;
            }

            //mark the spots with '-'
            for(var l = 0; l < array[i].width; l++){
                for(var m = 0; m < array[i].height; m++){
                    matrix[j+l][k+m] = "-";
                }
            }
            //pack the head of the block with data
            matrix[j][k] = array[i].width+"x"+array[i].height+"x"+nonzero;
        }
    }
}

var tablestring = "";
for(var i = 0; i < Omatrix.length; i++){
    tablestring += "<tr>";
    for(var j = 0; j < Omatrix[i].length; j++){
        tablestring += "<td>"+Omatrix[i][j]+"</td>"; 
    }
    tablestring += "</tr>";
}

document.getElementById("table1").innerHTML += tablestring;

var tablestring = "";
for(var i = 0; i < Omatrix.length; i++){
    tablestring += "<tr>";
    for(var j = 0; j < Omatrix[i].length; j++){
        //going trough all the cells
        if(matrix[i][j] === "-"){
            //a cell with a "-" will not be displayed
            continue;
        }
        else if(typeof(matrix[i][j]) === "string"){
            //a cell with a string is the head of a big block of cells.
            var add = "";
            var data = matrix[i][j].split("x");
            if(data[0] !== "1"){
                add += " rowspan="+data[0];
            }
            if(data[1] !== "1"){
                add += " colspan="+data[1];
            }
            tablestring += "<td"+add+">"+data[2]+"</td>"; 
        }
        else{
            //a normal cell
            tablestring += "<td>"+Omatrix[i][j]+"</td>"; 
        }
    }
    tablestring += "</tr>";
}

document.getElementById("table2").innerHTML += tablestring;
```

Comment: This is similar enough to the direction I was considering that I'll just vote for it.  If you wanted to modify this to look for square areas first, and give them priority, you could do so, It would only change the larger "4" block, in this instance.  Good work!

Comment: Squares do now have full priority. This also means that it will prefer [3x2] + [2x2] above [5x2] and [2x2] + [2x2] above [4x2].

Comment: This is great if the tables are small.  It's something like O(n^6), so it's going to blow up rapidly.

Comment: @Gene If you count the amount of rows (in the example 7), it's approx. O(n^4), but if you count the amount of cells (7x7), it's O(n^2) for each cell added. Still quite a lot, so if you have ideas to reduce that, please tell me!

Comment: @XiozZe You can never have a [2x2] + [2x2] if the shape is [4x2]. The second [2x2] would not have a value. So you would end up with [2x2] and two times [1x2] (assuming the [4x2] not starts at the top row, otherwise you have a really big problem)

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. This works in most browsers. It uses the array method reduce which is perfect for these type of problems.

```
var matrix = [
  [ 1, 2, 0, 3 ],
  [ 0, 4, 0, 0 ],
  [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ],
];

var table = matrix.reduce(function(rows, row){
  rows.push(row.reduce(function(newRow, col){
    var lastCol = newRow[newRow.length - 1];
    if (!col && lastCol) {
      lastCol.colspan = (lastCol.colspan || 1) + 1;
    } else if (!col && !lastCol) {
      var lastRowCol = rows[rows.length-1][newRow.length];
      if (lastRowCol) lastRowCol.rowspan = (lastRowCol.rowspan || 1) + 1;
    } else {
      newRow.push({value:col});
    }
    return newRow;
  }, []));
  return rows;
}, []);


var expected =  [
  [{value : 1, rowspan: 2}, {value:2, colspan: 2}, {value:3}],
  [{value : 4, colspan: 3}],
  [{value : 5}, {value:6}, {value:7}, {value:8}]
];

table.should.eql(expected); // Passed OK
```

Comment: If you want to convert the resulting matrix to html just a jQuery template or angular ng-repeat or such.

Comment: Thanks, looks good, but doesn't produce a correct table for some matrices: http://jsfiddle.net/ThQt4/. - or did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

*Note*
When I wrote this answer, I hadn't yet read through your comments, where you expressed a preference for sqare representations (ie: colspan=2 rowspan=2 for 3). I'll add a more flexible answer once I find the time.

A simple loop approach might just be enough to tackle this:

```
var cells = [
    [ 1, 2, 0, 3 ],
    [ 0, 4, 0, 0 ],
    [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
],i, j, c, r,tmpString, tbl = [];
for (i=0;i<cells.length;++i)
{
    tbl[i] = [];
    for (j=0;j<cells[i].length;++j)
    {
        if (cells[i][j] !== 0)
        {
            if (j === 0)
            {//This only works for first indexes (if not, cells[0][3] + cells[1][3] yields rowspan, too)
                r = 1;
                while(i+r < cells.length && cells[i+r][j] === 0)
                    ++r;//while next row == 0, add rowspan count
            }
            c = 1;
            while(c+j < cells[i].length && cells[i][j+c] === 0)
                ++c;
            tmpString = '<td';
            if (j === 0 && r > 1)
                tmpString += ' rowspan="' + r + '"';
            if (c > 1)
                tmpString += ' colspan="' + c + '"';
            tmpString += '>'+cells[i][j]+'</td>';
            tbl[i].push(tmpString);
        }
    }
    tbl[i] = tbl[i].join('');
}
console.log('<table border=1 cellpadding=10><tr>' + tbl.join('</tr><tr>') + '</tr></table>');
```

The varnames are clumsy (at best), but the names are `i` and `j` are just simple index/loop counter variables. `c` counts the colspans that'll be required at any given time, and `r` does the same for the rowspans. `tbl` is an is an array of arrays that'll be used to build the table string.
`tmpString` is just a variable that is used to concat each cell together. Its main reason of existence is to avoid horrid statements like:

```
tmp[i].push('<td' + (j === 0 && r > 1 ? ' rowspan="' + r + '"' : '')
    + (c > 1 ? ' colspan="' + c +'"' : '') + '>' + cells[i][j] + '</td>'
);
```

Anyway, the output, after some indentation has been added is this:

```
<table border=1 cellpadding=10>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1</td>
        <td colspan="2">2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Which is, I'd say, pretty close to what you were after

Comment: Thanks, it looks like there are problems with some configurations: http://jsfiddle.net/ThQt4/

Answer (score 1):

From your example, the colspan is the one plus the number of empty cells to the right of a none empty cell and the rowspan is similarly one plus the number of empty cells below a none empty cell.

Where things get more interesting is when a none empty cell has empty cells both to the right and below. How do you want to handle that situation?

Comment: Theoretically, it should be possible to represent every matrix with colspans only (assuming there are no empty rows), but I'm striving for more aesthetically pleasant look, with possibly square-shaped cells. In my example, it would be `colspan=2 rowspan=2` for `3`

Answer (score 1):

Here In your Java script you have to do following

```
var str="<table border=1 cellpadding=10>"
var rows=data.lenght();
if(rows>0)
{
    for(int r=0;r<rows;r++)
    {
        var cols=data[r].lenght();
        if(cols>0)
        {
            str+="<tr>";
            for(int c=0;c<cols;c++)
            {
                var colstospan=getnext0(r,c,0); //This function will give you columns to be span... defination given below
                str+="<td colspan="+colstospan+">"+data[r][c]+"</td>";
            }
            str+="</tr>";
        }
    }
}
str+="</table>";


str will give you table you require...
```

Here is the Defination of `getnext0`

```
function getnext0(rows,cols,count)
{
    if(data[rows][cols+1]==0)
    {
        return getnext0(rows,cols+1,count+1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

I hope this will work for you....
please ignore if syntax error in `lenght()` function...

Comment: Thanks, your code doesn't work for me for some reason. Could you make a jsfiddle or jsbin demo?

Comment: `data.length()` should be `data.length;` an array's `length` is a magic property, not a function

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem Ya Thanks